# Are questions about electrical scooters (e.g. M365) on-topic on this site?

Tags: discussion, scope

I want to ask a question about the maintenance of an electrical scooter and I want to know if this is on-topic in this community. This is the closest community I could find to ask about this, that's why I am thinking of asking it here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Electric scooter questions would be on topic. It doesn't matter what the motivation for the vehicle is (ie: internal combustion, electric, etc), as long as it is about Maintenance & Repair of the vehicle or accessories for the vehicle. Purchase questions about parts are not on topic.

Answer (score 0):

Over on Bicycles.SE we consider the differentiator to be the "main power source"

If the scooter has pegs or footrests only, and requires some kind of fuel to move, then its a motorbike and on topic for mechanics.SE

If your scooter has pedals and you can ride it on the pedal/leg power alone, then its a bicycle with an electric assist and is on topic at https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/

The consensus on batteries, charging, and repacking them has been for Electronics.SE